# Generate dataweave from YAML of REST service I need to invoke?

Tags: yaml, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a rather large and complex YAML that I was given by the developer of a REST service to which I need to POST complex data payloads. Can I automatically generate the Dataweave for the payload of my POST request from the YAML they provided? Would save me a lot of effort.

Comment: Not able to understand your question. From the yaml what is the output you are planning to generate. Need more details to understand what exactly you are looking for

Comment: The YAML is the input payload spec for the REST service I will be calling. I need to generate this payload using Dataweave within my service. I want to generate that Dataweave which will output JSON which conforms to the YAML.

Comment: Please provide an example input and expected output. How large is the YAML? Could you clarify what is the complexity? Is there any specification?

Comment: I cannot share the YAML due to security concerns. The YAML specifies the format of the JSON payload that I need my dataweave to output. I simply was looking for a tool or way to generate dataweave code that would output JSON in the format specified by the YAML. It would just need to copy all of the property names from the YAML to the dataweave in the proper order and containment etc...

Comment: Questions asking us to [recommend or find](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. What is on-topic would be to describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Infin8Loop Actually, I recently implemented the reverse of exactly what your asked. The binary I created takes a Json and turns to yaml

Answer (score 1):

Yes REST Generator does this https://restgenerator.com/.  It takes RAML, OAS, WSDL or a Postman Collection as input and returns you the whole API coded including the dataweave.

Answer (score -1):

By "generate the dataweave" I believe you meant JSON.

You won't be able to get an exact Json, but you can get a schema. You can use this project. https://github.com/raml-org/ramldt2jsonschema. It's very easy to use if you follow the instructions.

However if you ought to have the Json with the example values you have in your Yaml, then you either have to code it yourself or wait till someone makes it.